# Getting battery status even when the application is closed

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-alarms

Hey I am trying to make an application that tells me when the battery is full when the phone is connected to power. 
I made a service and used a broadcast receiver in that to check the battery status.
Whenever i connect or disconnect the phone from the power, my app crashes. The service still runs and i get the notification when battery is full.

I dont know why is the app crashing again and again. 
Here is my code

public class Srvc extends Service{

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     final IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED); 
     this.registerReceiver(this.br, ifilter);


    System.out.println("started the service");


    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}



public final BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("inside on recieve");

        chckbttry(intent);

    }
};

private void chckbttry(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("inside chckbttry method");

    final int currLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    final int maxLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharged = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
    final int percentage = (int) Math.round((currLevel * 100.0) / maxLevel);

    if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING)
    {
         System.out.println("calling the BrdCst_strt");


     if (percentage == 100 || isCharged==true) {

         System.out.println("bttry fully chrged");
         Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),PlayMus.class); //call another activity
         i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         i.putExtra("msg", "Battery fully charged");
         getApplication().startActivity(i);
     }
    else
     {
        System.out.println("not yet charged");
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Test.class);
         i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         i.putExtra("msg", "Battery not fully charged");
         getApplication().startActivity(i);


    } 
    }

    if (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING)
    {
        System.out.println("unregistering the service");
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

} 

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("service stopped");
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

}

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use Service for it. Are you know anything about service?

Comment: no. as i said, i am new to it. i found many answers where they talk about getting a service and using it, but i dont get it. Can you please explain it to me? it would be really heplfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System messages like the battery level are sent as a *Broadcast* through the whole system. You can receive them with a so called ***BroadcastReceiver***.

While *Activities* have an UI, you need to use a ***Service*** which are meant to be used for longer work in the background while your App is not visible. Your App has to be started at least once before for you to be able to start this *Service*.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MyService service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (service == null) {
            // start service
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            startService(i);
        }
        // finish our activity. It will be started when our battery is full.
        finish();
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("MyService", "onStartCommand");
        // do not receive all available system information (it is a filter!)
        final IntentFilter battChangeFilter = new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        // register our receiver
        this.registerReceiver(this.batteryChangeReceiver, battChangeFilter);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver batteryChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            checkBatteryLevel(intent);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // There are Bound an Unbound Services - you should read about the differences. This one is an unbound one.
        return null;
    }

    private void checkBatteryLevel(Intent batteryChangeIntent) {
        // some calculations
        final int currLevel = batteryChangeIntent.getIntExtra(
                BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        final int maxLevel = batteryChangeIntent.getIntExtra(
                BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        final int percentage = (int) Math.round((currLevel * 100.0) / maxLevel);

        Log.d("MySerive", "current battery level: " + percentage);

        // full battery
        if (percentage == 100) {
            Log.d("MySerive", "battery fully loaded");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getApplication().startActivity(intent);
        }
        // do not forget to unregister
        unregisterReceiver(batteryChangeReceiver);
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml: **You need an entry for your Serivice - just like for an Activity.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mybatteryservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mybatteryservice.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.mybatteryservice.SecondActivity" >
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.mybatteryservice.MyService" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please let me know if you have any more questions!

Best regards
Vincent

Comment: i used your code and added one more thing i.e i also check if battery status is charging or not. when ever i connect my phone to charger or disconnect it, my app crashes. I dont know why, can you please help?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I have not checked stack overflow last days. Do you still need help? Just show me your log cat.

Answer (score 1):

Write your code as a service.   Its simple to use

```
public class ClassName extends Service{

         //write your code


       }
```

also add it on manifest

```
<service android:name="com.test.ClassName">               
           </service>
```

/////////////////// New Codes ///////////////////

```
public class BatCheck extends Service {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


            BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                  boolean isCharged = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

                      if(isCharged){

                         // write your code

                          }
        }
    };

}
```

}

//////////////// Another One ///////////////////

In your manifest

```
   <receiver android:name=".BatCheck">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In your activity

```
    public class BatCheck extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharged = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

              if(isCharged){

                 // write your code

                  }

    }
}
```

Comment: and what do i do exactly in the class? as i said, i am new, i dont know much.

Comment: you have to implement a intent receiver for battery intents. Just take a look on the android developer site.

Comment: thanks a lot...these were really helpful..!!! Do i need to add a permission in manifest?

Comment: please tell me a little more. if i create a class BatChckBR that extends a broadcast receiver and then call this class from my service, will it work the same? and can i just have ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED as i only need to check as long as the power is connected?

Comment: If you have a broadcast receiver like my code no need of service. It works when there is a change in battery level

Comment: int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

Can you mail me if you have more doubts my ID is cirilmannoor@gmail.com

Comment: @aradhna Check the error log, if you can't identify the error please post the error log.