# Broadcast receiver is not working when app on foreground or active

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am building app regarding battery indicator and i am using code from this post.

[Getting battery status even when the application is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758200/getting-battery-status-even-when-the-application-is-closed)

it is working fine when app is closed, but when an app is active or on foreground it did not work or did not send any broadcast.

This is main activity from i start service

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private MyService service;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (service == null) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(i);
    }

    finish();
}
```

}

Following is the service code.

```
public class MyService extends Service{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("MyService", "onStartCommand");
    // do not receive all available system information (it is a filter!)
    final IntentFilter battChangeFilter = new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    // register our receiver
    this.registerReceiver(this.batteryChangeReceiver, battChangeFilter);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
private final BroadcastReceiver batteryChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        checkBatteryLevel(intent);
    }
};

private void checkBatteryLevel(Intent batteryChangeIntent) {
    // some calculations
    final int currLevel = batteryChangeIntent.getIntExtra(
            BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    final int maxLevel = batteryChangeIntent.getIntExtra(
            BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    final int percentage = (int) Math.round((currLevel * 100.0) / maxLevel);

    if(percentage==100)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Last.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(intent);

    }
    // do not forget to unregister
    unregisterReceiver(batteryChangeReceiver);
} }
```

And when following activity start i did not receive any broadcast.

```
public class Last extends Activity {
Button btnCancel;
Uri notification;
Ringtone r;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);

    notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();


     btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopsound);

     btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             r.stop();
        }
    });

}  }
```

Comment: Because you call this line unregisterReceiver(batteryChangeReceiver); after you start your activity.

Comment: but it works fine when app is closed.

Comment: from what i read from your Service class, it will detect if the battery level is at 100% then it will start Last Activity and stop (unregister) all broadcast receiver. So it will make sense if when the Last Activity opened, the broadcast will no longer received

Comment: so should i removed unregisterreceiver ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, 
when you start application in first time, you see nothing, just service is started and a broadcast receiver is registered. When battery level will be changed, the method **checkBatteryLevel()** is calling and the broadcast receiver will be unregistered. As result you have never received a new changing of battery level.

Comment: so should i never call  unregisterReceiver right ??

Comment: @user1999284 you should call unregisterReceiver, when you want to stop listening the action. For example you can call unregisterReceiver when service will be destroyed.

Comment: if i unregistered receiver then how can i register it again ??

Comment: the receiver will be registered when **onStartCommand** will be called. Read more about [service](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: So, it should be registered. You can add logs to your code. It helps to understand what happening.